# I want to know the approximate n for this inequality.

Tags: inequality, combinations

Hi i have tried to calculate the approximate $n$:

$$
\sum_{k=12}^n \binom nk \left(\frac1{10}\right)^k\left(\frac9{10}\right)^{n-k}\frac{{}_{198}H_{k-12}}{{}_{198}H_k} \geqslant \frac{99}{100}.
$$

this is the inequality.

the symbol H means combination with repetition.
$$
 _{ n }{ H }_{ r }\quad =\quad { _{ n+r-1 }{ C }_{ r }\quad =\left(\begin{array}{c}n+r-1\\ r\end{array}\right) } 
$$

i tried to put left side in geogebra, but failed.
i don't know what to put.

Comment: This is a duplicated of [your earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3523260/i-dont-know-how-to-calculate-this-combination-equation) which was closed because people did not recognize $_nH_r$.  Have you tried putting in Stirling's approximation?

Comment: Try using Mathematica, there is a box on the RHS where there are symbols like $\sum$ or $\frac{\square}{\square}$... the only part that might be complicated is in the $\binom a b$ part which you could write as a fraction $\frac {a!}{(a-b)!b!}$

Comment: really appreciate your answer.

Comment: i forgot suing stirling's approximation. really thanks :)